# Include is not a known directive message in VS 2022

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a `.NET 7 Blazor App` and I am trying to update my `app.css` to change some border settings depending on which breakpoint we are using.

I'm receiving following error message:

```
"include" is not a known '@' directive.
```

Here is what I'm adding to `app.css`.

**The Code:**

```
    @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    .nav-item {
            border-bottom: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-color: #fff;
        }
    }
```

I attempted to add the Bootstrapp.SASS NuGet package. The project is using Bootstrap 5.1.

Comment: Try `@@include`

Comment: You are using SASS/SCSS syntax in a regular CSS file. You will need to compile SCSS down to CSS if you want to use @include for an example.